# php use bacon/bacon-qr-code to write to browser without writing to screen first

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I have the following PHP code to generate a QR code and display to the browser.

The following code works:

```
      $renderer = new \BaconQrCode\Renderer\Image\Png();
      $renderer->setHeight(100);
      $renderer->setWidth(100);

      $writer = new \BaconQrCode\Writer($renderer);

      $uniqueCode = "Hello World";
      $fileName = "temp.jpg";
      $writer->writeFile($uniqueCode, $fileName);
      echo "<div class=\"closing\">"
      . "<img src=\"$fileName\" /></div>";
```

What I want to do is send the qr directly to browser without first writing to a file.  Is this possible?

My next move is to save the whole url to a pdf file using dompdf package.
Thanks.

Ken

Answer (score 6):

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $writer->writeString($uniqueCode);
```

Comment: This works, Just the answer I was looking for.  Thank you again.